# ng-repeat is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below object should generate table rows for parent and child objects under one table(as siblings). how it can be, I used ng-repeat-start but no use. I need it for equal alignments.

```
[
{'name':'parent1','children':[{'name':'child1'},{'name':'child2'}]},
{'name':'parent2','children':[{'name':'child1'},{'name':'child2'}]}
......
]
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="parent in obj">
<td>{{parent.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
<td>{{child.name}}</td>
</tr>
...........
```

Table should generate like below:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Parent1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>child1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>child2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Parent2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>child1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>child2</td>
</tr>
......
</table>
```

Comment: 'whell it works as it is expected of it. First it displays all parent names, then nothing, because there is no parent variable in controller scope.

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="parent in obj">
        <td>{{parent.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
        <td>{{child.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end="">
    <tr/>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh this looks interesting :) I have to try this ;)

Comment: I tried this, but its not printing. is repeat start compatible with AngularJS v1.0.5.

Comment: @shaik, no it requires version 1.2+

Answer (score 1):

All is ok, because this code

```
<tr ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
<td>{{child.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

is out of this scope

```
<tr ng-repeat="parent in obj">
<td>{{parent.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

if you want to achieve what you want you can make a flat array like this

```
[
{'name':'parent1'},
{'name':'children1'},
...
...
]
```

and iterate over it