# Significance of ng-repeat-start vs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand the significance of `ng-repeat-start` over `ng-repeat`. The angular documentation provides the following example for `ng-repeat-start`

```
<header ng-repeat-start="item in items">
  Header {{ item }}
</header>
<div class="body">
  Body {{ item }}
</div>
<footer ng-repeat-end>
  Footer {{ item }}
</footer>
```

But the same can be achived using `ng-repeat`,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <header>
    Header {{ item }}
  </header>
  <div class="body">
    Body {{ item }}
  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer {{ item }}
  </footer>
</div>
```

Can someone explain the significance of `ng-repeat-start`.? Thanks.

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is to get rid from wrapping `<div>` element.

Comment: http://www.nitishkumarsingh.com/blog/advantage-of-ng-repeat-start-and-ng-repeat-end-repeating-over-multiple-elements/

Comment: @Rasalom - Thanks. I can understand the diffrence now.

Comment: Example use case for "ng-repeat-start and end" [ng-repeat is not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28578025)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The significance of these two directives is similar: they repeat HTML-tags. The difference is only that with help of `ng-repeat-start` you could repeat few tags starting from tag with `ng-repeat-start` and finishing by `ng-repeat-end`.

For example you have next code:

```
<div>
  Item # {{item}}
</div>
<div>Whether you repeat me?</div>
```

So now we can add 2 directives for these code.
**With `ng-repeat`:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  Item # {{item}}
</div>
<div>
  This code will not be repeated
</div>
```

**With `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:**

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in items">
  Item # {{item}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end="">This code will be repeated</div>
```

So now you can see that in the first case just `div` with `ng-repeat` directive repeats, but in the second case both your `div`s will be repeated.

You can see Demo and play with it:

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/R778lWTABVF3Hy16CAca

Answer (score 28):

I thought I'd add my answer, as no one touched on a very important reason for having these directives available.  `ng-repeat` will not work correctly in certain scenarios when using html tables.  Using `ng-repeat-start` is the only way to accomplish certain things.

Imagine you want to display your data like this using html tables:

[image: Grouped Data Mockup]

And this is your data set:

```
groups = [
    {
        name: "Group 1",
        customers: [
            {id: 123, name: "Foo Inc.", state: "NJ"},
            {id: 234, name: "Bar Co.", state: "AZ"}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Group 2",
        customers: [
            {id: 345, name: "Baz LLC", state: "CA"}
        ]
    }
];
```

Using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` you can do this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="group in groups">
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">{{group.name}}<td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="customer in group.customers">
        <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.state}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notice the `ng-repeat-end` followed by another regular `ng-repeat`.  This ends the matching `ng-repeat-start` but initiates another repeat on the `customers` array, since we are still in the original `ng-repeat-start` scope when calling `ng-repeat-end`, we still have access to the `group` object.

Keep in mind, *this is a very trivial example*, but as the table structure becomes more complicated, the only way to accomplish things like this is to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`

Comment: This is awesome!  Thanks for the great example.

Comment: @NathanFriend not a problem.  I figured since the documentation is pretty lacking that I should give an example on how useful it is.

Comment: Very useful example. Not a trivial example, it should be typical example :)

Answer (score 2):

> The ng-repeat-start directive works the same as ng-repeat, but will repeat all the HTML code (including the tag it’s defined on) up to and including the ending HTML tag where ng-repeat-end is placed