# angularjs ng-repeat dependent on another ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array (helper.makes) like so:

```
[0] => { make: 'BMW', models: ['3 series','5 series'] }
[1] => { make: 'Honda', models: ['Camry','Corolla'] }
```

In my select I want the user to select make and then the model select will update accordingly.  Here is my code so far:

```
<label>
  <p>Make</p>
  <select ng-model="make">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in helper.makes | orderBy: 'name'">{{ value.name }}</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>
  <p>Model</p>
  <select ng-model="model">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in helper.getModelByMake(make) | orderBy: value">{{ value }}</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Before I simply used an associative array so I could do helper.makes[make] but that kept turning it into an object and angular refused to order it.  Doing it this way I created the function getModelByMake which simply loops through the list of makes, finds the right one and returns it's models array.

The problem is, that does not seem to update as the person changes the make.  I believe it is attempting to load once, seeing that no make is selected and returning blank results.

What method would be best for such an instance in AngularJS?  Is there something awesome AngularJS can do here that I am unaware of?

Comment: Have you tried `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`?

Comment: Let me look those up.

Comment: I do not see how that would be useful.  It seems that it would simply allow me to repeat code outside of the tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940257/significance-of-ng-repeat-start-vs-ng-repeat

Comment: I extremelly recommend you to use `ngOptions`, which one was made especifically for `<select>`.

Comment: I didn't know that even existed, I will check it out thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I extremely recommend you to use [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of `ngRepeat`. `ngOptions` was made exactly for this kind of things.

Also, you don't need to use `ngChange` directive or `$watch`, you just need to get the models `array` from the `ngModel` selected in the *first* `ngOptions`, as below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.makes = [  
     {  
        "make":"BMW",
        "models":[  
           "3 series",
           "5 series"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "make":"Honda",
        "models":[  
           "Camry",
           "Corolla"
        ]
     }
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <label>
    <p>Make</p>
    <select ng-model="make" ng-options="objMake as objMake.make for objMake in makes">
    </select>
  </label>
  <div ng-if="make">
    <label>
      <p>Model</p>
      <select ng-model="model" ng-options="model for model in make.models">
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** I used `ng-if` no `hide` the second select when the first `select` has no selection.

Comment: You are right, this seems like the more angular way of doing it.  It avoids quite a bit of useless code.  I did it this way and simply added the orderBy in the ng-options. Thank you for the help and keeping me within the angular way!

Comment: A pleasure to help :)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know then how I would set the default make would you?  Now that the value is in reference to an object, I'm not sure how I would set that manually.

Comment: Let me see if I got you.. do you want to set a default value for the first `select`?

Comment: I want to select the default value of the make select to something like "BMW", after that is set it should load the model ngoptions then I want to set that default value to something like "5 series."

Comment: Then, do it in your controller: `$scope.make = $scope.makes[0]`

Comment: ok, so it seems then I will have to loop through the makes finding which one has the name of "BMW." There is no cleaner way?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, or you really need it to set by default "BMW" and "BMW" isn't at the **1st.** position `[0]`?

Comment: I really have to set it to BMW or Honda depending on what the client has saved as his previously owned vehicle.  Some clients will have this, others will not.

Comment: Unfortunately you should use a `find` of JS then.. do you know how to use?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-change` in the make option and create something like this:

```
<label>
  <p>Make</p>
  <select ng-model="make">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in helper.makes | orderBy: 'name'" ng-change="getModelByMake()">{{ value.name }}</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>
  <p>Model</p>
  <select ng-model="model">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in helper.model | orderBy: value">{{ value }}</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Then in your `getModelByMake()` function, you get the make `ID` and get the models.

Comment: Yes, this works properly, thank you.  However since the function getModelByMake was in the helper service I had to send the make.  (eg. ng-change="helper.getModelByMake(make)"

Comment: I ended up choosing developer033's answer because it was more angular.  This one did work though, thank you.