# How to create a Repeating Multiple Elements Using Ng-repeat-start and Ng-repeat-end in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a table where on click of one column row a new rows get display below that table. I mean normal table will be there and a + icon will be there on click of that + icon below that row 3-4 new rows will get displayed and again if i click on then + icon it should get close.

I got some success with one inner row but I want to show 3-4 rows like that for reference.
[check code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OsNSeJWUShkKlJBJYO2b)

```
  <tr class="trigger" ng-repeat-start="car in carList | filter:tableFilter" ng-click="main.activeRow = car.name">
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding, you want something like add & remove on the row itself. Before I start plz read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940257/significance-of-ng-repeat-start-vs-ng-repeat) about difference between ng-repeat and ng-repeat-start if it helps.

*Further to add about ng-repeat-start and -end* source:[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

---

> The ng-repeat-start directive works the same as ng-repeat, but will
>   repeat all the HTML code (including the tag it's defined on) up to and
>   including the ending HTML tag where ng-repeat-end is placed.

```
<header ng-repeat-start="item in items"> Header {{ item }} </header>
<div class="body">    Body {{ item }} </div>
<footer ng-repeat-end>   Footer {{ item }} </footer>
```

---

Simply add `$scope.carList.push(newcarlist);` to add new rows.
Plz check working fiddle [link here](https://jsfiddle.net/sudi065/c165whbu/)

Comment: No I am looking for a table when I just want to display a table with one patent row when I click on one colomn of  the parent row I should be able to see his child below that row child can be one or ten.  Means below one table row there is another table .

Comment: @JoydeepRoy- Just to reconfirm- Suppose if i have Parent table A then onclick of any row on Table A - you want to create another **Child row** in Table A itself? like this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/BggZU1f4faEONUpXr6Ve?p=preview) ?